# Optimize query using HQL / Antlr.Runtime.NoViableAltException

Tags: c#, nhibernate, hql

I have code:

```
if (request.OrderBy != "PricesCount")
                query = query.ApplyOrder(request);
else
   {
       if (request.OrderDirection == "ASC")
          {
            query = query.ToList().OrderBy(p => p.Prices.Count).AsQueryable(); //must be optimize!
          }
       else
          query = query.ToList().OrderByDescending(p => p.Prices.Count).AsQueryable(); //must be optimize!
  } 
 query = query.Page(pageNumber, pageSize);
 var result = query.ToList();
```

`query` has type `NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryable<Book>`

I must remove the `ToList()` which causes loading all Books from DB.

If I try to use some code:

```
query = query.OrderBy(p => p.Prices.Count);
...
var result = query.ToList();//I have Antlr.Runtime.NoViableAltException

Exception of type 'Antlr.Runtime.NoViableAltException' was thrown. [.Take[Book](.Skip[Book](.OrderBy[Book,System.Int32](NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryable`1[Book], Quote((p, ) => (p.Prices.Count)), ), p1, ), p2, )]
```

Comment: You need to specify criteria for pulling back rows, or a tolist will pull back all rows in the database like you are seeing.

Comment: What kind of optimization are you talking about?

Comment: @Anon, when I use ToList() -> I have request to DB (select all Books).

Answer (score 0):

```
result = query.Where(p=>p.Price > 5).ToList(); //put whatever filter you want
```

You don't need to do `.ToList().AsQueryable().ToList()` like you are in your first segment.

If you can't filter results, then you should implement some sort of paging:

```
result = query.Skip(x).Take(y).ToList(); //You will need to send in X and Y based on what page you are on and how many items per page you use
```

---

`result = query.Where(p=>p.Price>5).OrderBy(p=>p.Prices.Count).ToList()`

Like I said in comments, if you don't provide a where clause, or if you don't do `.Take(y)` then this will return all items in the database.  You will pass in X and Y yourself if you do `.Skip(x).Take(y)`, you need to determine what is appropriate paging for your application.

Comment: I need "order by count sth". Where is sorting in your code, why use p.Price > 5? Where I must get x and y? I don't understand, can you explain me, please? I edit my post, please, read it.